# Ice cream stabilizer - locust gum - use and cooking procedure

Tags: ice-cream, stabilizers

I have a locust gum (powder). I searched online and it needs to be heated at least to 165 F to properly hydrate the gum.
I have a few questions:

- should I still use eggs in the recipe? Won't it be too gummy?
- should I cook all liquid ingredients, including fruit, with the locust gum so all liquid is incorporated by the gum?
- how long should I cook it? Just until it reaches the right temperature? Or keep cooking like 20 minutes? Is there a minimum and maximum?

I could not find much clear directions on how to use it for ice cream, bit this site helped a lot: http://icecreamscience.com/locust-bean-gum-in-ice-cream/#44_heating_and_hydration
'm just trying to get more real experience from others.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Eggs don't contain any starch.

Comment: @moscafj thank you, I probably expressed it in the wrong way. I heard that egg already does something similar to the gum, so I just wondered if it would be too much.

Comment: another point. Unless you're talking about something that doesn't contain water (like oil, or gasoline), you don't hydrate a liquid. I think you mean hydrate the gum

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza I don't how my mind did not stop me from writing "hydrate the liquid"! Yes, I meant the gum. Obrigado, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

LBG hydrates at 80C (176F); which might be a bit high for eggs. You should simply the cook the milk+cream with LBG until it hydrates and thickens; then proceed with your recipe, i.e while tempering the eggs at the right temperature as the mixture cools down...

I would mix in the fruits at the end to the cold mixture, as heat can alter the taste of fruit greatly.